# Class exporting iterators on two collections

Tags: java

Consider the case where a class contains two collections.  Is it possible to provide iterators over both collections **in a way that callers can use to iterate over?**

My simple example:

```
public class Bar {
    public static class Beer { /* ... */ }
    public static class Wine { /* ... */ }
    private Set<Beer> beers = new HashSet<Beer>();
    private Set<Wine> wines = new HashSet<Wine>();

    public Iterator<Beer> beerIterator() { return beers.iterator(); }
    public Iterator<Wine> wineIterator() { return wines.iterator(); }
}
```

So far, so good.  We can declare the methods that return the iterators, but the way I'm trying to do it, the caller can't use the iterator to, well, iterate.

```
void caller(Bar bar) {
    for (Beer beer: bar.beerIterator()) { // <-- Compilation error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to return `Iterator`s rather than `Collection`s or perhaps `Iterable`s? `Iterator` is a rather uncommonly-used interface.

Comment: yeah, just return `Iterable<Beer>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point in returning iterators is to protect your collections from changes while giving client ability to use `foreach` loops, then the most clear way will be to use `Collections.unmodifiableSet` wrapper. You can return it as `Iterable` interface to hide the implementation even further.

```
public static class Bar {
    public static class Beer { /* ... */ }
    public static class Wine { /* ... */ }
    private Set<Beer> beers = new HashSet<Beer>();
    private Set<Wine> wines = new HashSet<Wine>();

    public Iterable<Beer> beerIterable() { return Collections.unmodifiableSet(beers); }
    public Iterable<Wine> wineIterable() { return Collections.unmodifiableSet(wines); }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Bar.Beer beer : new Bar().beerIterable()) {

    }
}
```

This approach is better than one suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen, because it protects your collection from being changed from outside. When you return `.iterator` of your original collection, client is still able to modify original collection by calling `remove()` method. Wrapping in `unmodifiableSet` prevents that.

However, be aware that client still can modify returned instances of `Beer` and `Wine` during the iteration, if they are mutable. If you want to be fully protected from changes, you need to make deep defensive copies of your collections before returning them to client.

Comment: Great answer.  I'm accepting Aivean's over Tim's simply because it's less code and I'm a bit leary of having both Beer and Beers.

Comment: Nit: I'd name the methods `beers()` and `wines()` - the fact that they're `Iterable` is visible in the return type.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to define 2 inner classes inside `Bar` which return custom iterators for beer and wine:

```
public class Bar {
    public static class Beer { /* ... */ }
    public static class Wine { /* ... */ }
    private Set<Beer> beers = new HashSet<Beer>();
    private Set<Wine> wines = new HashSet<Wine>();

    private class Beers implements Iterable<Beer> {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Beer> iterator() {
            return beers.iterator();
        }
    }

    private class Wines implements Iterable<Wine> {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Wine> iterator() {
            return wines.iterator();
        }
    }

    public Beers beers() {
        return new Beers();
    }

    public Wines wines() {
        return new Wines();
    }
}
```

You can use the custom iterators like this:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
// add some beers and wines here

for (Beer beer : bar.beers()) {
    System.out.println("Found another beer: " + beer);
}

for (Wine wine : bar.wines()) {
    System.out.println("Found another wine: " + wine);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I'm accepting Aivean's over yours simply because it's less code and I'm a bit leary of having both Beer and Beers, but this definitely does directly give what I asked for.  thanks.

Comment: Downvoted, because there are several drawbacks in this approach: 1. If you don't care about defending immutability of the collections, you can just return them instead of creating wrappers. `Set` already implements `Iterable`. 2. If the point was in preserving the immutability, then it just doesn't work, as client still can call `iterator.remove()` and modify collection. 3. Even following this approach, there is no need to create explicit classes, anonymous inner class  `return new Iterable<Beer> { ...} ` is sufficient.